# Receiving javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException when decrypting a file

Tags: java, android, exception, encryption

I am building a class in Android Studio which is responsible for encrypting and decrypting contents of files.

The issue is that whenever I try to decrypt a file (i.e. the data of the byte[] parameter of the decrypt() method excluding the IV) the following exception is raised at

```
// last line of decrypt method
return cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
```

As far as I read, "This exception is thrown when a [`Cipher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) operating in an AEAD mode (such as GCM/CCM) is unable to verify the supplied authentication tag.".

I'm pretty sure that the key, the IV and the encrypted text are matching in the encryption and the decryption methods (according to the results of the Log statements).

Does someone have an idea where the problem may lay in?
This is the class:

```
package elsys.project;

import android.security.keystore.KeyGenParameterSpec;
import android.security.keystore.KeyProperties;
import android.util.Log;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.GCMParameterSpec;

public class EncryptionAndDecryption {
    private static byte[] IV;
    private static SecretKey SECRET_KEY;
    private static String alias;
    private static byte[] EncryptedData;
    public static byte[] encrypt(String text, String secretKeyAlias) throws Exception{
        try {
            alias = secretKeyAlias;
            generateKeyIfNotAvailable(secretKeyAlias);

            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
            keyStore.load(null);
            SecretKey secretKey = (SecretKey) keyStore.getKey(secretKeyAlias, null);

            Log.d("encryption", (secretKey == null) + "");

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);

            byte[] encryptedData = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            EncryptedData = encryptedData;

            byte[] iv = new byte[12];
            IV = iv;
            SECRET_KEY = secretKey;
            Random random = new Random();
            random.nextBytes(iv);

            byte[] fileContent = new byte[iv.length + encryptedData.length];
            System.arraycopy(iv, 0, fileContent, 0, iv.length);
            System.arraycopy(encryptedData, 0, fileContent, iv.length, encryptedData.length);
            return fileContent;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("encryption", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] fileContent, String secretKeyAlias) {
        try {
            Log.d("decryption", (secretKeyAlias.equals(alias)) + " 1");

            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
            keyStore.load(null);
            SecretKey secretKey = (SecretKey) keyStore.getKey(secretKeyAlias, null);

            Log.d("decryption", (secretKey == null) + " 2");
            Log.d("decryption", (SECRET_KEY == null) + " 3");

            Log.d("decryption", SECRET_KEY.equals(secretKey) + " 4");

            byte[] iv = new byte[12];
            System.arraycopy(fileContent, 0, iv, 0, 12);

            Log.d("decryption", Arrays.equals(IV, iv) + " 5");

            byte[] encrypted = new byte[fileContent.length - 12];
            System.arraycopy(fileContent, 12, encrypted, 0, encrypted.length);

            Log.d("decryption", Arrays.equals(encrypted, EncryptedData) + " 6");

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new GCMParameterSpec(128, iv));

            return cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("decryption", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static void generateKeyIfNotAvailable(String secretKeyAlias) throws Exception {
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
        keyStore.load(null);

        // Check if key exists, if not, generate a new one
        if (!keyStore.containsAlias(secretKeyAlias)) {
            KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(
                    KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, "AndroidKeyStore");

            KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder builder = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                    secretKeyAlias,
                    KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT);

            builder.setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
                    .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
                    .setUserAuthenticationRequired(false);

            keyGenerator.init(builder.build());
            keyGenerator.generateKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried using different values for the authentication tag's size but that didn't work.

Comment: Please never use `Random`  together with crypto - never ever. Random is not suitable gory crypto. Use `SecureRandom` instead.

Comment: BTW your code one major flaw: you are generating the IV after the encryption has already be performed. So the IV is never used and thus useless. You have to provide the IV in the init method to make it have an effect on the encryption.